# I am having trouble with my Calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

I am new to C++. My first goal is to make a successful Calculator program a Win32 Console Application, but I keep getting an error. I put this code:

```
cout << "Do you want to continue? N/Y" << endl;
cin  >> ny;

if (ny == "Y") goto start;
if (ny == "N") goto end;
```

But it keeps on going to end either way.

This is the code for 'end':

```
// End - Properties
system("cls");
system("title Basic Calculator -  End");
system("color 4F");

// End - Start
ny == "0";
cout << "Are you sure you want to end? N/Y" << endl;
cin  >> ny;

if (ny == "N") goto start;

cin.get();

return 0();
```

And in end it also always ends the program.

If you find out the mistake, please let me know.

-Danish Humair

Full Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
start:
    // Program - Properties
    system("cls");
    system("title Basic Calculator - Main Screen");
    system("color 1F");

    // Program - Setup
    int input;
    int x;
    int y;
    char ny [10];

    // Program - Start
    cout << "Please choose an operation from the following." << endl << endl;
    cout << "1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3. Multiplication \n4. Division" <<endl << endl;
    cin  >> input;
    if (input = 1) goto addition;
    if (input = 2) goto subtraction;
    if (input = 3) goto multiplication;
    if (input = 4) goto division;
    cin.get();

addition:

    // Addition - Properties
    system("cls");
    system("title Basic Calculator - Addition");
    system("color 2F");

    // Addition - Start
    cout << "Please input your first number." << endl;
    cin  >> x;
    cout <<endl << "Please input your second number."<< endl << endl;
    cin  >> y;
    cout <<endl <<endl << "The answer is " << x+y << ".\a" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to continue? N/Y" << endl;
    cin  >> ny;

    if (ny == "Y") goto start;
    if (ny == "N") goto end;

    cin.get();

subtraction:

multiplication:

division:

end:
    // End - Properties
    system("cls");
    system("title Basic Calculator -  End");
    system("color 4F");

    // End - Start
    ny == "0";
    cout << "Are you sure you want to end? N/Y" << endl;
    cin  >> ny;

    if (ny == "N") goto start;

    cin.get();

    return 0();
}
```

Comment: You should definitely replace those `goto`s.

Comment: I just had a total Apple BASIC flashback.

Comment: Did you learn function before?

Comment: There is no real error. It is just that the program is not working the way I want to. I want that if you press Y, it will go back to the beginning of the program and when I press N, I want it to end the program. But, if I press either of those, it ends the program.

Comment: @DanishHumair: Go ahead and edit this into your post (while removed the "error" part) so that everyone can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues need to be addressed.

1) Declare ny as `std::string ny;` You'll need to add `#include <string>`.  This will avoid a buffer overflow.

2) As mentioned before you need to change your if statements.

```
if (input == 1) goto addition;  // Use '==' for comparison
if (input == 2) goto subtraction;
if (input == 3) goto multiplication;
if (input == 4) goto division;
```

3) Make sure you check for lowercase y and n

```
if (ny[0] == 'Y' || ny[0] == 'y') goto start;  // notice the single quotes
if (ny[0] == 'N' || ny[0] == 'n') goto end;  

// ...
// Also change the following
ny[0] = '\0';  // Not really necessary since you assign it immediately after
// ...
if (ny[0] == 'N' | ny[0] == 'n')
```

4) Your `return` statement is incorrect.  Change it to:

```
return 0;  // Doesn't need parenthesis
```

As a professional programmer I must suggest you not use goto statements and encapsulate your algorithms in functions.  Below is an example based on your original code.  FYI, I've verified it compiles on Visual Studio 2010 Professional

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Forward declarations
void addition();
void subtraction();
void multiplication();
void division();

int main()
{
    bool again = true;

    // Program - Setup
    int input;
    std::string ny;

    while(again)
    {
        // Program - Properties
        system("cls");
        system("title Basic Calculator - Main Screen");
        system("color 1F");

        // Program - Start
        cout << "Please choose an operation from the following." << endl << endl;
        cout << "1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3. Multiplication \n4. Division" <<endl << endl;
        cin  >> input;
        cin.get();

        if (input == 1) {addition();}
        else if (input == 2) {subtraction();}
        else if (input == 3) {multiplication();}
        else if (input == 4) {division();}
        else 
        {
            cout << "Invalid input\n"; 
            again = false;
        }

        cout << "Do you want to continue? N/Y" << endl;
        cin  >> ny;
        cin.get();

        if (ny[0] == 'Y' || ny[0] == 'y')
        {
            again = true;    
        }
        else
        {
            // Ask if they are sure
            system("cls");
            system("title Basic Calculator -  End");
            system("color 4F");

            cout << "Are you sure you want to end? N/Y" << endl;
            cin  >> ny;
            cin.get();

            if (ny[0] == 'Y' || ny[0] == 'y')
            {
                again = false; 
            }
            else
            {
                again = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void addition()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    // Addition - Properties
    system("cls");
    system("title Basic Calculator - Addition");
    system("color 2F");

    // Addition - Start
    cout << "Please input your first number." << endl;
    cin  >> x;
    cout <<endl << "Please input your second number."<< endl << endl;
    cin  >> y;
    cout <<endl <<endl << "The answer is " << x+y << ".\a" << endl << endl;
}

void subtraction()
{

}

void multiplication()
{

}

void division()
{

}
```

Comment: :| Still not working. Perhaps its something with my compiler 'Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate'.

Comment: I was incorrect using a char for cin.  I've updated my solution to use std::string which will avoid a buffer overflow.

Comment: @Danish Humair - I'm glad it worked out for you, don't forget to mark an answer.  Which route did you end up going?  With the functions or the goto statements?

Answer (score 3):

if (input = 1) goto addition

I think you should check (input == 1) but you are assigning it to input (input= 1).

Code should be:-

```
if (input == 1) goto addition;
if (input == 2) goto subtraction;
if (input == 3) goto multiplication;
if (input == 4) goto division;
```

Comment: Gautam, those if statements are not characters they are integers. Even though, a lot thank you for your reply. I tried it but still not working... - Danish Humair

Answer (score 1):

I have done few changes,
 1) Declared ny as character instead of array.
 2) Checking for small as well as capital letters.

I have added comments wherever i have done changes.
I hope this helps.

```
    // #include "stdafx.h" //If you get error include this
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    start:
        // Program - Properties
        system("cls");
        system("title Basic Calculator - Main Screen");
        system("color 1F");

        // Program - Setup
        int input;
        int x;
        int y;
        char ny;  //Dont declare it as array ny[10]

        // Program - Start
        cout << "Please choose an operation from the following." << endl << endl;
        cout << "1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3. Multiplication \n4. Division" <<endl << endl;
        cin  >> input;
        if (input == 1) goto addition;
        if (input == 2) goto subtraction;
        if (input == 3) goto multiplication;
        if (input == 4) goto division;
        cin.get();

    addition:

        // Addition - Properties
        system("cls");
        system("title Basic Calculator - Addition");
        system("color 2F");

        // Addition - Start
        cout << "Please input your first number." << endl;
        cin  >> x;
        cout <<endl << "Please input your second number."<< endl << endl;
        cin  >> y;
        cout <<endl <<endl << "The answer is " << x+y << ".\a" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to continue? N/Y" << endl;
        cin  >> ny;

        if (ny == 'Y'|| ny == 'y') goto start;   //Check for both Y & y
        if (ny == 'N' || ny == 'n') goto end;    //Check for both N & n

        cin.get();

    subtraction:

    multiplication:

    division:

    end:
        // End - Properties
        system("cls");
        system("title Basic Calculator -  End");
        system("color 4F");

        // End - Start

        cout << "Are you sure you want to end? N/Y" << endl;
        cin  >> ny;

        if (ny == 'N' || ny == 'n') goto start;

        cin.get();

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do all things jmstoker said except 1) and 3). Instead change your code to

```
if (ny[0] == 'Y') goto start;
if (ny[0] == 'N') goto end;
```

It works at least in my compiler (Microsoft Visual C++ 2011 Express)

Here's the complete code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
start:
    // Program - Properties
    system("cls");
    system("title Basic Calculator - Main Screen");
    system("color 1F");

    // Program - Setup
    int input;
    int x;
    int y;
    char ny [10];

    // Program - Start
    cout << "Please choose an operation from the following." << endl << endl;
    cout << "1. Addition \n2. Subtraction \n3. Multiplication \n4. Division" <<endl << endl;
    cin  >> input;
    if (input == 1) goto addition;
    if (input == 2) goto subtraction;
    if (input == 3) goto multiplication;
    if (input == 4) goto division;
    cin.get();

addition:

    // Addition - Properties
    system("cls");
    system("title Basic Calculator - Addition");
    system("color 2F");

    // Addition - Start
    cout << "Please input your first number." << endl;
    cin  >> x;
    cout <<endl << "Please input your second number."<< endl << endl;
    cin  >> y;
    cout <<endl <<endl << "The answer is " << x+y << ".\a" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Do you want to continue? N/Y" << endl;
    cin  >> ny;

    if (ny[0] == 'Y') goto start;
    if (ny[0] == 'N') goto end;

    cin.get();

subtraction:

multiplication:

division:

end:
    // End - Properties
    system("cls");
    system("title Basic Calculator -  End");
    system("color 4F");

    // End - Start
    cout << "Are you sure you want to end? N/Y" << endl;
    cin  >> ny;

    if (ny[0] == 'N') goto start;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```